# How to implement Synchronize.js using Browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronize, browserify

I searched many forums, blogs and sites before reaching here.
I am making a WebApp and need to use Synchronize.js to avoid WebSQL messy async.
When adding the command in my html page.

```
    var synchronize = require('synchronize');
```

I get an error :

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Reading the web I came to a conclusion Browserify was required to use the node notation 'require'.
I installed Browserify from npm and headed to the file location, and ran this code:

```
    browserify sync.js sync > bundle.js
```

Error produced was :

```
    Error: module "fibers" not found from "/..my dirs../js/sync.js"
```

I tried:

```
    browserify collection.js > bundle.js
```

where collection.js contains

```
    var fs   = require('fs');
    var synchronize = require('synchronize');
```

This compiled without issues.

When I add the bundle.js file to my html page I get an error in the console:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'v8' of undefined
```

--- Can someone please explain in details on how to use Synchronize.js and Browserify as I have reached a blocked wall from the tutorials online.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: long story short: not possible

Comment: Why is that? What I understand is that Synchronize.js can work on browser.
Have you any Idea on how to possibly force async code to run sync on the browser?

Comment: Fibers is a native module and will not run in Browsers. Synchronize is a fibers wrapper, so i doubt it runs in the Browser.

Comment: check this: https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs

Answer (score 2):

synchronize.js rely on Fibers extension to node.js. Sadly it is impossible to use Fibers with browsers, only with node.js.

So the answer is - synchronize.js can't be used with Browsers, only with node.js

Comment: Maybe a soft solution can be created that does not rely on fibers. But depends on artificial ones.